# Check uniqueness of two columns in two tables using validator in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, validation

I am taking input of a field named "email", and checking it using laravel validator. The problem is I want to make sure that the "email" data should be unique in two columns in two different tables. (Sellers and Buyers must not have the same email in their "email" column).

I am able to check the input from one table and column, How should I check the input in both columns? Below is my code.

```
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'emailOrNumber' => ['required', 'string','email','max:255','unique:usersNew,email'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8'],

         ]);
```

The above code check email only in usersNew table and in email column, How can I check both tables in here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `unique` rule twice. Once for each table you need to check a field for uniqueness:

```
'email' => [..., 'unique:table1', 'unique:table2'],
```

When you don't pass a column to the `unique` rule it will use the current field name being validated, `email` in this example.

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Validation - Rules - `unique`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-unique)

Answer (score 1):

just use it

```
'email' => 'unique:table1,your_column_name|unique:table2:your_column_name_2'
```

or use it answer https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/validate-a-field-from-2-tables-with-different-message

Comment: After using your approach it shows me below error,
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email|unique:sellers:email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `usersNew` where `email|unique:sellers:email` = faisal@yahoo.com)

Comment: the `:` after `table2` should be a `,` ...  `...|unique:table2,your_column_name_2`  .... since the OP is using an array the first and second unique (rules) need to be separated ... `[..., 'unique:table1,email', 'unique:table2,email']`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => ['required',     'string','email','max:255','unique:user|unique:email'],
    'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:9'],

     ]);
```

In this code `unique:username|unique:email` will assume the email and username as unique

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```
 return Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'emailOrNumber' => ['required',     'string','email','max:255','unique:usersNew|unique:email'],
    'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8'],

     ]);
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: thanks for your reply but the I have column name email in my tables, you have not mentioned column Name in above code, where should I place the column name?

Comment: use this   -  `'unique:usersNew,column_name1|unique:email,column_name2'`

Comment: didnt work. shows below error
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email|unique:sellers:email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `usersNew` where `email|unique:sellers:email` = faisal@yahoo.com)